# Validar Fecha de la forma dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm en c#?

Tags: c#

Estoy intentado validar una fecha de la forma dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm
pero al hacerlo con el codigo de abajo, me validaria cualquier formato de fecha correcta.

```
           try
            {
                DateTime.Parse(Fecha);
                FechaError = 0;
            }
            catch
            {
                FechaError = 2;
            }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puedes usar la función de `DateTime.ParseExact`, la cual lanza una excepción si hay un error:

```
var dateTime = DateTime.ParseExact("30/01/2017 03:45","dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm",CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

También puedes revisar la función `DateTime.TryParseExact`

```
DateTime fecha;

if (DateTime.TryParseExact("30/01/2017 03:45", "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm", null, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, out fecha)
{
    Console.WriteLine(fecha);
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Fecha invalida"); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A ver si entendí... ¿Intentas validar una fecha únicamente mediante el formato: "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm"? Por ejemplo, si escribiera "15/07/1992 11:23" esta fecha sería aceptada y pasaría la validación. Mismo que no debiera ocurrir si yo escribo algo como "11:23 p. m. 15-7-92" (Aun cuando la conversión DateTime.Parse de esta última fecha se efectuara con excito)

Sí comprendí bien tu pregunta, quizá puedas solucionar el problema con el siguiente código:

```
        string Fecha = "Alguna fecha cualquiera";
        int FechaError = 0;
        DateTime FechaValida = new DateTime();

        try
        {
            FechaValida = DateTime.Parse(Fecha);
            if (FechaValida.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm") == Fecha)
                FechaError = 0;
            else
            {
                FechaValida = new DateTime();
                FechaError = 2;
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            FechaError = 2;
        }
```

Por cierto... este código solo validará variables DateTime cuya hora sea de 12:00 a. m. - 11:59 a. m. a menos que cambies el formato de aceptación a: "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm tt" o "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm"